# CodeMirror (JS Code Highlight) text in textarea exceeds textarea width

Tags: css, textarea, overflow, codemirror

I've been working with CodeMirror today to create a little environment where I can edit some PHP code that is stored in a database (yes, I know this could be harmfull, but the PHP code is not accesable for normal users).

Everythings works great, the editor works, code highlighting works, indent tabs work, but there's one thing that's bothering me for a while now and I can't seem to find a solutions to this. The code that is within my CodeMirror editor textarea, which is longer than the textarea exceeds the textarea and will disappear somewhere out of my screen (see the screenshot at the end of this post).

I would like to have this code to continue on a line below (without adding an extra linenumber ofcourse). Is this a known issue and/or easy to fix?

Here's a screenshot:
    http://www.pendemo.nl/codemirror.png

Thanks in advance.

//Edit: it's fixed

Ok, got it figured out, seemed to be all in the CSS file! Here's the fix for anyone that's interested:

```
.CodeMirror {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 700px;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-family: monospace;
  _position: relative; /* IE6 hack */
}
```

overflow-y: auto (height is being done auto, so no need for a vertical scrollbar).  overflow-x: scroll; to force CodeMirror to add a scrollbar instead of exceeding the width of the textarea. And they give a fixed width (px or percentage). You can also add a max-height, but if you do you perhaps have to set overflow-y to scroll aswel.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for me, the scroll bar is hidden / doesnt work

Comment: Haven't looked into it for a couple of months now since the code is/was running perfect.

Comment: @ChrisEdwards Hey were you able to find a fix? Stuck in a similar problem but this solution is not working for me.

Comment: @newbie oh wow this was like 5 years ago, no clue sorry. No longer on the project :-/

Comment: Instead of "edit--it's fixed", it's best to post a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so people can distinguish the question in its original context from the solution. Screenshot link is also broken.

Comment: I guess it's a bit strange to comment on a question that has it's 10th anniversary coming up any moment. Of course the screenshot isn't working (plus, I posted an answer below that references to the solution in the question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fixed, see question for the details if anyone else might bump onto this problem.

Answer (score 10):

It's easy to enable word wrap in CodeMirror by setting the `lineWrapping` option to `true`. Example:

```
    <textarea id="code" name="code">
      ...
    </textarea>

    <script>
      var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
        tabMode: "indent",
        matchBrackets: true,
        theme: "night",
        lineNumbers: true,
        lineWrapping: true,
        indentUnit: 4,
        mode: "text/javascript"
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As Chris commented above, the solution described in the question doesn't (always?) work any more.

However, adding `max-width: ...ex;` to CSS does seem to force a horizontal scrollbar.

(Without that, e.g. just using `width: ...`, only configuring CodeMirror with `lineWrapping: true` (as in fywe's answer) could prevent it from blatantly stretching the box for long lines, but lineWrapping has its own drawbacks (e.g. navigation-unfriendly Home/End handling), so that may not really help.)